# How to include file in cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp

I am using cakePHP 2.4.4. I have some common HTML/PHP code which has to be displayed multiple times like:

```
if(condition1){
    //show html
}else if(condition2 && condition3){
    //show html
}
```

Like this there are more than 10 condition. I don't want to repeat the same HTML. I tried to include the file. It works for path like include ("D:/common/common.php"). But I want it to be within project folder. I put it in element but I can't load it multiple times. And if I put it in view/myview/ then I cannot give proper path. What is the solution?

Comment: Have you created different element files for different conditions?

Comment: @ObjectManipulator   OP wrote: ***...I am using cakePHP 2.4.4...*** Perhaps i can't read correctly...

Comment: No .I need same element for multiple condition

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you to create different .ctp files as elements.

For example, element_one.ctp for condition 1, 2, 3.
element_two.ctp for condition 4, 5, 6.. etc.

View/Element should have element_one.ctp and element_two.ctp.

And then, in your main view page, mention the following:

```
 if (condition1 || condition 2 || condition 3) {

     echo $this->element("element_one");

 }  else if (condition 4 || condition 5 || condition 6) {

     echo $this->element("element_two");
 }
```

Comment: Ya right.But i need to create more than 20 files in which 10 files have same data

Comment: Well, don't "create" files which have same data. If 10 is supposed to have same data, then maybe you'd need to create about 14-15 files. That's too much of a hassle but it can be done. Another way would be to use a lot of if/else if statements in the view itself without using elements.

Comment: I tried it for first it works.But page number exceeds more than 10 thousand line :( No other way?